# How to amend Python code to work in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

In another thread, I was given this code to import large numbers of dxfs into QGIS. This code works in QGIS2.18, but they just released QGIS 3.0 and have changed the codes to use a different version of Python. This code doesn't work in 3.0. Running it generates a series of requests to set the CRS, but nothing then imports.

How can I edit this code (or other codes) to be compatible with QGIS 3.0? What was changed?
I tried an online converter but it didn't alter anything.

```
import glob, os
path = "E:/aawork/aasites/aa-all towns and villages/Hemelhempstead/osmap 2012/"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.dxf"):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, 'name', 'ogr')
    subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for subLayer in subLayers:
        geom_type = subLayer.split(':')[-1]
        if geom_type == 'LineString':
             uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=%s" % (layer, geom_type,)
             dfx_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0]
             layer_name = "%s - %s" % (dfx_file_name,geom_type,)
             sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, 'ogr')
             QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

Comment: Btw:
Test the PlugIn Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter
Multiple files can be imported at the same time (batch import). One click for a lot of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import glob, os
path = "E:/aawork/aasites/aa-all towns and villages/Hemelhempstead/osmap 2012/"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.dxf"):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, 'name', 'ogr')
    subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for subLayer in subLayers:
        if 'Point' in subLayer:
            uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=Point" % (layer)
        if 'LineString' in subLayer:
            uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=LineString" % (layer)
        dfx_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0]
        sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, dfx_file_name, 'ogr')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

---

For the CRS, you could set a specific one as default when loading your dxf files which can be done from the the menubar:

```
Settings > Options > CRS > CRS for new layers
```

Comment: That's already done. It doesn't enable the code to work. Apparently Python has changed how the separators work, but I don't know how they changed them.

Comment: OK, I tried the amended version and checked that the CRS is set to default, but it's still asking me for a crs for each and every one of the dxfs in that folder. That's a lot of dxfs.
The set to default doesn't seem to affect the dxf import.

Comment: @PJLightning - I can't replicate your issue. Are you using the official release version? The version I have is 3.0.0-Girona (you can check this from the menubar `Help > About`).

Comment: Another dxf converter does work for small numbers of dxfs, but it's about ten times slower than the python code. It's not a great option for large areas. It did import the dxfs eventually, though, which I guess is the main thing.

Comment: yes, that's the one I have. It may have something to do with the origins of the dxfs. They were created by a program called LL2dxf which converts the old NTF format to dxf. They imported fine in version 2.18.

Comment: Oh wait! I thought I'd set a default crs, but I'd set it for the project, not for the layers.
It's working. I'll select your code as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @PJLightning - Most welcome, glad you got it working :)